# Concat values of two arrays

Tags: r, string

Having two equal sized arrays with string values,

e.g.

`c('a', 'b', 'c')` 
`c('d', 'e', 'f')`

I want to merge their values and make one array like this:
`('ad','be','cf')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste0` which is `Vectorized` and does an elementwise concat

```
paste0(v1, v2)
#[1] "ad" "be" "cf"
```

---

Or another option is `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(v1, v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
v2 <- c('d', 'e', 'f')
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `%s+%` operator from `stringi` package:

```
v1 %s+% v2
```

**or**

`stri_join` from `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_join(v1,v2,sep="")
```

Output:

```
[1] "ad" "be" "cf"
```

data:

```
v1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
v2 <- c('d', 'e', 'f')
```